# Can't send mail from Gnus, but message works?

Tags: gnus, email

I can send mail with message, via `C-x m`. However, when I try to send a message from Gnus, via `m` in the summary buffer, or other commands like `S r`, `F` etc, the message shows up in my sent folder in Gnus, but doesn't actually get sent. i.e., everything appears to work as expected from Gnus, no errors are generated, but the recipient doesn't get the email.

Do I need to do something specific to configure Gnus to send mail? I have the following config which appears to be sufficient for message:

```
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "<my-mail-server>")
       send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
       smtpmail-smtp-server  "<my-mail-server>"
       smtpmail-stream-type  'ssl
       smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
```

Comment: Have you tried `(setq message-send-mail-function 'message-send-mail-with-sendmail)` ?

Comment: @politza No. I don't have sendmail set up, but I can take a look at that when I get back to my home computer.

Comment: I guess, I misread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. The customization variable `message-send-mail-function` was set to `message-send-mail-with-sendmail`. My configuration (in the question above) appear to have over-ridden this when sending mail from `message`, but not when sending/posting mail from `gnus`. Somewhere in the posting process I think `gnus` was querying the function `message-send-mail-function`, which returned the value of the `message-send-mail-function` variable, which was wrong.

Setting `message-send-mail-with-function` to `smtpmail-send-it` seems to have fixed this problem. I suspect the ultimate source of the problem is that sendmail was installed on my machine but misconfigured. Emacs detected this and set the default values based on that. Maybe.